# name basestring is not defined when clicking save

Tags: python, django

```
# if this is a file path, we know it is a large file
if isinstance(request.session['initial_files'], 
  basestring):
```

This was done in python2 and django 1.8, now that I moved to python 3.6.9 and django 2.2, it's crashing there with the message:

> basestring is not defined.

What am I MISSING to import?

```
File "/home/bsd/.virtualenvs/BSD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

    File "/home/bsd/.virtualenvs/BSD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
      115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "/home/bsd/.virtualenvs/BSD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
      113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    File "/home/bsd/.virtualenvs/BSD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    File "/home/bsd/PycharmProjects/BSD/BSD_3_1/tifact/views.py" in update
      465.         if isinstance(request.session['initial_files'], basestring):   # if this is a file path, we know it is a large file

    Exception Type: NameError at /tifact/update/submit/1515
    Exception Value: name 'basestring' is not define
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#porting-to-python-3-0, and search for "`basestring`" on that page. This probably won't be the only incompatibility you'll encounter.

Comment: Did you actually convert your code to Python3 (e.g. using ``2to3``) or do just run your Python2 code unmodified?

Comment: i am compiling code unmodified, and wherever i get error i fix it to python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Code, Hope it will help you.

```
try:
  basestring
except NameError:
  basestring = str
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK in the newer python, the builtin basestring abstract type was removed.
try str